# FInd Dupes in Two Tables Code Needed Please

Tags: sql-server

TABLE_1

```
Customer_ID      Sub_ID         
-----------------------         
12345            100            
23456            200            
34567            300            
45678            400            
56789            500
```

TABLE_2

```
Customer_ID     Sub_ID
----------------------
12345           101
12345           300
12345           103
23456           200
23456           200
23456           100     
34567           300
34567           300
45678           300
56789           800
```

Desired Result

```
Customer_ID     Sub_ID
-------------------
34567           300
```

In Table_1 there are no duplicates for Customer_ID and each Customer_ID only has one Sub_ID.
Table_2 can have Duplicate Customer_ID's and Numerous or Single Sub_Id's. Need to find only distincts in Table_2 by Customer_ID and Sub_ID that exactly matches Table_1 Customer_ID and Sub_ID

My Attempt:

```
SELECT  Customer_ID,Sub_ID  
FROM Table_A A  
WHERE A.Customer_ID,A.Sub_ID not in (SELECT B.Customer_ID,B.Sub_ID
                  FROM Table_B B);
```

Comment: please make an attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write your query like following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.CUSTOMER_ID, 
                T2.SUB_ID 
FROM   TABLE_1 T1 
       INNER JOIN TABLE_2 T2 
               ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.CUSTOMER_ID 
                  AND T1.SUB_ID = T2.SUB_ID 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   TABLE_2 TI 
                   WHERE  TI.CUSTOMER_ID = T1.CUSTOMER_ID 
                          AND TI.SUB_ID <> T1.SUB_ID)
```

This will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id and t1.sub_id=t2.sub_id
and t1.customer_id not in 
(select t3.customer_id from table1 t3 inner join table2 t4 
on t3.customer_id=t4.customer_id and t3.sub_id <> t4.sub_id)
```